# Is there any way to date auto format using Keyboarddatepicker using material ui4 in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datepicker

We are using material ui Keyboarddatepicker to display date using datepicker in ReactJS, we have set date format using props in ReactJS `format=DD/MMM/YYYY` so date will be set like "29/Apr/2020".

It is working perfectly when we select date from datepicker. Date is set in required format, but we are having problems when we enter the date manually from keyboard or typed it with another date format, like dd/mm/yyyy or dd-mm-yyyy, or when we enter a numeric value. Then it should be set based on typed value, like when we type 10122020, then it should be set in date format like "10/Dec/2020".

How can I convert all date input formats into our required date format?

We are using below code for datepicker.

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider libInstance={moment} utils={MomentUtils}>
  <KeyboardDatePicker
    autoOk={true}
    value={selectedDate}
    format="DD/MMM/YYYY"
    onChange={handleDateChange}
  />
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```